# Can't get if (number == 1) comparison to work

Tags: c++

I am working at a vending machine software. I cannot get the if statement to work. It just simply ignores it.

```
// Program.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    char number; 
    cout << "Hello. Please choose a drink type ! \n\n1.Coca-Cola \n2.Coca-Cola ZERO \n3.Pepsi\n" ;
    cin >> number;


    if (number == 1)
        cout << "Please tip in 8$";

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing a `char` variable to an `int` value. You need to change one or the other so they match. Either make `number` an int:

```
int number; 
...
if (number == 1)
```

or compare it to the character `'1'`:

```
char number;
...
if (number == '1')
```

The distinction here is between the number 1 and the character `'1'` which has an ASCII value of 49.

Comment: Regardless of the ASCII value, `number - '0'` will be the numeric value represented by the number when `number` has type `char`. That is, `char number; ... if (number - '0' == 1)` is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

As `number` is a character, you want the comparison to use a character and not the integer value 1. i.e.

```
if (number == '1')
```

Comment: Or use `if (number - '0' == 1)`.

Comment: Maybe, in this context. It's still a valid solution, and it leads to the "right" approach when converting `char` values to digits.

Comment: I'd go for `if ('1' == number)` to let the compiler reject the `if (number = '1')` typo.

Comment: Many compilers can pick up that bug these days